# How to figure out direction of text or page with tesseract

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ocr, tesseract

So I have been trying to figure this out for a whole day now. And I really hope someone will be able to help me out. 
I am trying to write a software, that will process a PDF document. Processing means, deleting empty pages and rotating pages that have been scanned upside down.

Obviously I need some kind of OCR library here, so I went with Tesseract. Detecting empty pages was easy enough. But the Orientation property doesn't seem to work at all (**EDIT:** by not working I mean it always says "PageUp"). But from what I gathered so far, this should give me a hint to whether or not my page is upside down. Am I missing something? Maybe something that has to be included in the tessdata folder for this?

I also tried the approach of testing for GetMeanConfidence, flip the image and then compare the MeanConfidences, because in theory the page that wasn't upside down, should be easier to read. But the difference is so minimal, that I don't think this is reliable.

And I switched the language attribute of the TesseractEngine. I tried "eng", "deu", and "osd". All with the same result.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(filepath);
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
path = Path.Combine(path, "tessdata");
path = path.Replace("file:\\", "");
var engine = new TesseractEngine(path, "osd", EngineMode.TesseractOnly);
using (var img = PixConverter.ToPix(image))
{
  using (var page = engine.Process(img, PageSegMode.AutoOsd))
  {
    var pageIterator = page.AnalyseLayout();
    pageIterator.Begin();
    var pageProperties = pageIterator.GetProperties();
    Console.WriteLine(pageProperties.Orientation.ToString() +" "+  
    pageProperties.TextLineOrder + " " + pageProperties.DeskewAngle + " " + 
    pageProperties.WritingDirection);
    Console.WriteLine(page.GetMeanConfidence());
   }
}
```

I expect an output that tells me if the page is upside down. So that I know if it has to be rotated or not. Performance doesn't matter!
I am also open for different approaches and libraries (as long as they're free).

Comment: I am not familiar with C&, but if you provide test image and pageProperties I can help you with testing/other solution.

Comment: BTW: if you are interesting in page orientation only you can try leptonica - there is LeptonicaSharp project. Have a look at  [pixOrientDetect](https://github.com/Phreak87/LeptonicaSharp/blob/2caf3ae7b1422dec8359ebcfe5714a856ab64530/CS_LIB/Functions/flipdetect.cs#L120) function.

Comment: Thank you! I will test this out next week. If I don't have any success I'll post a test image.