# Detect Tesseract 5.2 Image text orientation

Tags: c#, tesseract, orientation

Hello I am using Tesseract 5.2 to capture text from images but the problem is orientation of text in image file may vary, I am sharing 2 examples for the same.
[image: Sample 1]

[image: Sample 2]

below is the code to capture text from image

```
using (var engine = new Tesseract.TesseractEngine(path, "eng", Tesseract.EngineMode.Default))
{
    using (var page = engine.Process(img, Tesseract.PageSegMode.Auto))
    {
        return page.GetText();
    }
}
```

I just want to know the orientation of text and based on that capture the text in proper way but I don't know how to get this

Comment: Rotate images...

Comment: I have provided 2 samples, I don't know when sample 1 comes and when sample 2 comes

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871528/how-to-figure-out-direction-of-text-or-page-with-tesseract - LeptonicaSharp maybe your solution

Comment: privacy? what's that?

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract/Leptonica is all you need.

Want to add some caveats before answering though:

1. Tesseract's Auto OSD should handle this by default. Try that option first and you might find you are already getting the right results.
2. Tesseract-OCR is not suitable for handwritten text, which makes up most of your content (the answer on how to extract handwritten text is out-of-scope for this question).

You can find the orientation and also correct it using Tesseract libraries.

1. Make sure you have `osd.trainneddata` in your `tessdata` folder. OSD here stands for Orientation Script Detection, which actually enables you to understand the orientation. It can be found here if you do not have it: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/main/osd.traineddata
2. Use `Tesseract.PageSegMode.AutoOsd`. This is different than what you had before as it not only does Automated Page Segmentation but also does Orientation Script Detection.
3. Utilize `page.AnalyseLayout()`

   - This returns both the detected orientation of the text. It comes as an enum: (Page Up (0 degree, what you expect), Page Right (90 degree angle), Page Down (180 degree angle), and Page Left (270 degree angle).
   - It also returns the deskew angle that can be passed to Leptonica and fixed via rotation. You can do this through the Tesseract libraries however, no need to install another package.

```cs
 using (var pix = PixConverter.ToPix(image))
 {
     using (var page = engine.Process(pix, Tesseract.PageSegMode.AutoOsd))
     {
         using (var pageIter = page.AnalyseLayout())
         {
             pageIter.Begin();
             var pageProps = pageIter.GetProperties();
             // Get page orientation (Page Up, Page Down, Page Left, Page Right)
             var orientation = pageProps.Orientation;
             // Rotate image based on DeskewAngle (in radians)
             pix.Rotate(pageProps.DeskewAngle);
         }
                               
     }
}
```

I've ran this on your images and found that the orientation is found correctly for both sample images (for image 1 it detects as "Page Right", and for image 2 as "Page Left").

Answer (score 0):

you can use skew detection
i've tried in python libraries not c#
but here are the links may help you
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104248/Detect-image-skew-angle-and-deskew-image

[emgucv: pan card improper skew detection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550517/emgucv-pan-card-improper-skew-detection-in-c-sharp)

or:
you can create a python app(like simple .py file and run with cmd) or api(like flask), pass image to python app as input and get results and then use in c#.
here is some links to help you
https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/

[Python OpenCV skew correction for OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964634/python-opencv-skew-correction-for-ocr)

you don't need to know python just copy the codes

also i think EasyOCR better than Tesseract
https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR